# favorite icon in the address bar

Tags: icons, favorite

Does anybody know how Google load the favorite icon on their homepage?

There is no link tag in the head. So, I thought that the icon is loaded through JavaScript but that is not the case. I've cleared the cache and disabled the JavaScript and still there is a favorite icon in the address bar.

Thanks,
Teo

Answer (score 2):

A favicon.ico file in the root of the website will be displayed in most modern browsers - you don't need to explicitly link to it.

Comment: That is a default favicon, but in the address bar it is the Google's icon

Comment: Exactly as I said, the favicon.ico file in the root (linked in my comment above) displays the Google logo.